# Hadoop 2.5.0 uable to confi HWI with hive 0.12.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I am promoting with below error when i try using :9999/hwi/

i am promoting with below error, but my java path was set to JDK not JRE. please suggest me where to update so that it will refer to JDK instered fo rJRE

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hwi/. Reason:

```
Unable to find a javac compiler;
```

com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre"

Comment: Make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set and exported for the daemon reporting the problem, not for you.

Comment: Ya it was set java bin but it is looking jre as per GUI error HTTP 500